# Why can I not set cross-subdomain cookies via javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am trying both in javascript and in php to set cookies that will work cross-domain.

In PHP:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_set_cookie_params(60*60,"/",".example.com",false,false);
```

In JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = 'coo=21c4o2fnb2et aqj256; expires=Sun Feb 01 2015 23:40:16 GMT-0500 (EST); path=/;Domain=.example.com;'
```

In `.htaccess`:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

In `php.ini`:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

In the PHP response, I get:

```
PHPSESSID=togp8kh3ehst2iuf4t3egll7p0; expires=Sun, 02-Nov-2014 04:43:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com
```

So, the php response looks good to me, but the browser stores no cookies, for both the javascript and the php. Cookies do work on a single subdomain, but this site is now requesting cookie-required data from a different subdomain, so I'd like to get the cookies to work for the entire domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer your (duplicated) question:

[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

The trick is on the setting the cookie with the higher domain possible, which would be example.com, not .example.com (which is not even valid)

Comment: `document.cookie = 'coo=21c4o2fnb2et aqj256; expires=Sun Feb 01 2015 23:40:16 GMT-0500 (EST); path=/;domain=example.com;'` doesn't work either. I've looked at a few answers, hence why I have several methods listed. I think `.example.com` is correct, actually, although the newer standard allows `example.com`.